# Java regular expression needed to separate phone number and text in brackets

Tags: java, regex

I'd like a regular expression for Java that can take this string

+1 7183541169 (East coast)

And produce two groups

- +1 7183541169
- East coast

I'm having difficulty with escaping the round brackets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be:

```
^(.*)\((.*)\)$
```

This assumes no special format - it will accept digits or letters anywhere. The regex reads:

`^` - Start of the string
`(.*)` - some letters (captured group)
`\(` - literal `(`
`(.*)` - more letters  (captured group)
`\)` - literal `)`
`$` - end of string

Keep in mind it is a relatively easy task, and you can solve it with simple string manipulation.

Comment: +1 I was about to say you forgot to capture the first part, but then I saw that it was posted 2 secs ago and refreshed the page :)

Comment: This regular expression is to greedy, it'll match many strings wich will not be correct.

Comment: Thank you! One day I might get a feel for RegExes.. just not in my DNA for some reason.

Comment: @Tobias - the format can vary. As far as I know, it can be `+925-1-800-Regex (St. George's Mnt.)`

Comment: @Jim - if that is the case, why use a regex?

Comment: Ah ok, Jim hadn't specified the syntax, so i thought every target string will be exactly like the input.

Comment: @Kobi the code is nicely compact, so it suits my needs from that perspective.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(\+\d{1} \d+) \(((?:\w| |-)+)\)$/i
```

i don't know the rules for your string, but this should work.